# Using (+) in order to do a left join between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query

```
SELECT * FROM  acc, transactions
WHERE acc.CUST_NO (+) = transactions.CUST_NO 
AND transactions.TRANS_dATE  < '01-JAN-19'
AND transactions.CUST_NO = 215529
```

Currently if the customer does not have a transaction his account information will not show using the above query. How do i fix it using (+) in order to create a left join and show results of the table acc even if there is no transactions.

Comment: in the provided query you have the right join, if you want to use LEFT JOIN place (+) to the RIGHT side of the condition transactions.CUST_NO (+). But better to use the ANSI JOIN syntax anyway

Comment: i have added (+) to the right side but the issue still exists.

Comment: This non-ANSI syntax is ambiguous, because you define the joins on columns, not tables. It is highly recommended that you use ANSI syntax instead.

Comment: have you removed it from the left side? WHERE acc.CUST_NO = transactions.CUST_NO (+). And yes, use ANSI one, it's just cleaner, less ambiguous etc

Comment: On a side note: Don't compare dates with strings. `'01-JAN-19'` is a string that must be converted to a date, which may or may not work depending on the session's settings. Change this to `transactions.TRANS_dATE  < DATE '2019-01-01'`. `DATE '2019-01-01'` is a date literal that can directly get compared with your transaction date.

Comment: As to the old Oracle syntax: I see absolutely no good reason for using this anymore. I understand that Oracle once introduced this syntax, because that was a time when database vendors were ahead of the SQL standard committee. But that was a long time ago. Proper explicit joins were introduced in standard SQL in 1992, i.e. almost thirty years ago. Anyway, AFAIK in the old syntax you have to use `(+)` on every column of the outer joined table: `WHERE transactions.cust_no (+) = acc.cust_no AND transactions.trans_date (+) < TO_DATE('01-JAN-19', 'DD.MON.RR') AND transactions.CUST_NO (+) = 215529`.

Comment: Another side observation.  You should not be using 2-digit years in your date specification.  Do not repeat the mistakes of the previous millennium.  _ALWAYS_ use 4-digit years.  If you are too young to remember, do a little google research on "Y2k bug".

Answer (score 2):

`LEFT JOIN` the standard way:

```
SELECT *
FROM acc
LEFT JOIN transactions
    ON acc.CUST_NO = transactions.CUST_NO 
  AND transactions.TRANS_dATE  < '01-JAN-19'
  AND transactions.CUST_NO = 215529
```

Will "*show results of the table acc even if there is no transactions.*".

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you really want:

```
SELECT *
FROM acc a LEFT JOIN
     transactions t
     ON t.CUST_NO = acc.CUST_NO AND
        t.TRANS_DATE  < DATE '2019-01-01'
WHERE a.CUST_NO  = ;
```

You can filter on `CUST_NO`, but the filtering should be on `acc`, not on `transactions`.  That filter should be in the `WHERE` clause.

I also replaced the date constant with Oracle's recommended format for date literals.